# Presto on EMR - setting the environment variable

Tags: command-line-interface, emr, presto

I'm playing with the built in Presto in AWS EMR.
I want to get rid of the default pager...
in the Presto docs it says:

> this behavior can be overridden by setting the environment variable
>   PRESTO_PAGER to the name of a different program such as more, or set
>   it to an empty value to completely disable pagination.

This is probably trivial but I have no idea how to do this and couldn't find any information...

In the context of presto I think all I can do is run SQL..
Anyone with experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variable permanently in bash using the export command.  For example, to set the pager to the `cat` program, execute:

```
export PRESTO_PAGER=cat
```

To disable the pager entirely execute:

```
export PRESTO_PAGER=
```

Alternatively, you can set it on a per command basis in bash by prefixing the command line with the property.  For example:

```
PRESTO_PAGER=cat java -jar presto-cli.executable.jar --debug --catalog tpch --schema tiny --server http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: thanks but did not work for me. I'm running commands from terminal after SSHing to the EMR. I tried running thos commands in the hadoop context ([hadoop@ip 10-0-10-230 ~])...

Answer (score 1):

It is working normally if executed through putty terminal. Queries are showing the complete result now.

a) Navigate to the presto client path(/opt/presto) and set the environment variable:

export PRESTO_PAGER=more;

//To check if it is set properly or not..
echo $PRESTO_PAGER; //It should display more.

b) Then open the presto client:
  ./presto --server localhost:8080 --catalog hive --schema database

Now less pagination won`t happen in presto client and complete multi-line results would be displayed in the presto client terminal.